# How to convert malformed DateTime in XML source into valid DateTime

Tags: xml, datetime, malformed

I have XML source data that contains DateTime data in the wrong format, like so:

```
<ord_dt>9/12/2011 11:56:12 AM</ord_dt>
```

I need to import the XML into Excel, and have Excel recognize this as a date automatically. I can't add any formulas or data transformations in Excel, and I cannot have the users apply formatting or the like.

I have tried creating an XML schema (.xsd) that specifies the element type as dateTime, and adding this to the Excel workbook. The relevant section of the .xsd reads so:

```
<xs:element name="ord_dt" type="xs:dateTime"/>
```

Excel still imports the source data as text -- I am guessing because the dateTime format in the source does not follow the required XML standard, nor the default for Excel.

I am aware that the dateTime format for XML should be something like "2002-05-30T09:00:00", but the source data is generated by a legacy application belonging to a client, and I cannot get them to change it.

Is there any way to define my schema such that it would transform the dateTime into the correct format when bringing it in to Excel?

Comment: Can't just run it through an XML transformer first (XSLT, or otherwise)? This technically doesn't break any listed restriction ;-)

Comment: I agree, sanitize the data in some way prior to import.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pst, XML transformation using XSLT before import is what can solve this problem in given conditions...

Comment: Thanks for your answers and the suggestion to use XSLT. Without any real experience with XML or XSLT, I have no idea how to use XSLT to accomplish this. Any suggestions/pointers would be appreciated.